# Is it okay to ask a coworker/supervisor to give a talk?

Tags: etiquette, united-states

I'm a staff scientist in a medium-sized lab and I'm organizing a large event for high school students at my university, a large public research institution. I'd like to invite a professor or senior researcher to give a talk at the event.

Is it generally considered okay to invite your close collaborators (e.g. PI, direct supervisors) to give a talk?

I have no misconceptions about the importance of my event (it's not) but I don't want to violate some etiquette by asking someone in my lab to give a talk. What about other events, small conferences, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think it's perfectly acceptable that you invite colleagues to give a talk at an event or conference.

There are many advantages for them if they give such a talk, for example:

- disseminating their work
- practising speaking to a non-expert audience
- networking
- free coffee/ lunch/ biscuits

If they don't want to do it, they'll decline your invitation and you can ask someone else-- a good choice might be PhD students who will actively want or need to practice outreach and public engagement.

Anyway, whoever you decide to invite, I don't think you've got anything to lose by asking.

Comment: We don't have any PhD students, but good suggestion.

Comment: In fact - it generally is viewed as an 'honor'  that you consider someone capable of giving a good presentation on their research to a general audience at a school or organization you are supporting. (As opposed to, for example, using the work place as a place to find people to guilt into  buying chocolate bars, popcorn, or the fund-raising item du jour etc to help support your organization)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think there is no more-reasonable thing than to ask a colleague to explain their work or related things, to various audiences. The colleague may also reasonably decline, thinking that they cannot provide a suitable context, or that they do not feel comfortable attempting to communicate well to the anticipated audience, but these are secondary issues.

That is, some people will, *reasonably*, feel that their current work is not easily consumable by any sort of general audience... and that they cannot, or are not interested in, giving a talk that gives the more digestible background. Not every expert has a good "narrative" about their work.

But it is certainly reasonable to *inquire*. At best, one has experts "spreading the good word". At worst, experts will be disinclined. Nothing lost.